# finfo_* functions

Tags: php

The `finfo_*` functions return information about a file; the most interesting function is

```
string finfo_file(resource $finfo, string $file_name = NULL [, int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, resource $context = NULL ]])
```

The first parameter is a *resource*, which is just the information you want returned about the file; in my case, I want the `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE`, so I use the `finfo_open()` function:

```
resource finfo_open([int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, string $magic_file = NULL ]])
```

and end up with

```
$a = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)
echo finfo_file($a,$fileatt['tmp_name']);
```

to get the mime type of my uploaded file, and it all works fine

However, two questions:

- the 3rd (optional) parameter to `finfo_file` is `int $options = FILEINFO_NONE`, but this is the same as the 1st option to `finfo_open`; since it is required as part of the *resource* in the 1st parameter of `finfo_file`, why it is also an optional (`int`) parameter in the same function?
- second, the terms *resource* and the function name `finfo_open` seems to be fairly confusing; in the `mysql_*` functions, a *resource* is the result of a query, which I can comprehend to be a fairly complex object; however, *resource* here is just a string, so why does PHP make it seem more complex than it seemingly is? Similarly, normally anyplace where a file is being manipulated and one of the functions that need to be used has the word *open* in its name would initially (to me, anyway) imply that this is the function where the file stream is opened / initiated, whereas here it's used to specify the info you want from the file.  Is there any strange historic reason for these terms here?

Answer (score 1):

> the terms resource and the function name finfo_open seems to be fairly confusing; in the mysql_* functions, a resource is the result of a query, which I can comprehend to be a fairly complex object; however, resource here is just a string

No, the result of `finfo_open` is *a resource*. A resource can be anything, usually it's an identifier for an external program. In case of MySQL, a MySQL resource is an identifier for a connection opened by the lower-level mysql client libraries. A MySQL result resource is an identifier for a result open over a certain connection.

In case of `finfo_open`, there's a "magic file" that will be opened. This magic file contains MIME type information. You can specify a specific magic file to use as the second parameter to `finfo_open`:

```
resource finfo_open([int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, string $magic_file = NULL ]])
```

So the external resource here is the file handle to the opened magic file. If you're doing several finfo queries, you want to keep this file open, so this has been abstracted into a resource.

> the 3rd (optional) parameter to `finfo_file` is `int $options = FILEINFO_NONE`, but this is the same as the 1st option to `finfo_open`

That's a good question indeed, I have no idea what the thinking behind this is. Perhaps if you're doing the same kind of finfo query over and over, you can specify it as parameter once to `finfo_open`, instead every time you call `finfo_file`.